# Best practice when updating Django model fields? Is this what manager classes are for?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-managers

I am very new to Django and I am wondering what the best practice is for updating a field. Here is my model:

```
class Website(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  url = models.TextField()
  is_awesome = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Right now I have a separate helper file, WebsiteHelper.py, with many other functions not related to the database in it, but also this function for updating a specific field in the DB:

```
def __mark_needs_redone(Website):
  Website.update(is_awesome=True)
```

Is there a cleaner place for functions such as these to live, such as:

```
class WebsiteManager(models.Manager)
   #Execute function here
```

Is this how managers are supposed to be used? If not, what is the best practice here?

Comment: That code isn't even valid - `update` is a queryset method, not an instance one. Are you trying to update every Website at once, or just one?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is on the model the form is handling, You can override the **save()** method you access to the actual instance.

```
    class Website(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        url = models.TextField()
        is_awesome = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def save(self, commit=True):
            self.instance.is_awesome = True
            return super().save(commit)
```

Don't forget the **super().save(commit)** call after because the parent takes care of the saving logic

Answer (score 0):

Your `update()` is calling the wrong way, you should call it to the model queryset, not the instance.

If You need to call Your method for every `save()`, check the `pre_save signal`, but if You don't, use **Manager**.

```
class WebsiteManager(models.Manager):
    def mark_needs_redone(self, pk):
        self.get(pk=pk).update(is_awesome = True)
```

To your model Website add the Manager:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.TextField()
    is_awesome = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = WebsiteManager()
```

And the usage is:

```
Website.objects.mark_needs_redone(pk=1)
```

That code will mark `is_awesome` as **True** for `Website` with `pk=1`